# How do I load RData according to the user's inputs on R Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny, rdata

I am creating an app using R's Shiny app package.

I want to load specific RData according to the user's inputs. However, when I run the app it can't seem to be loading the RData properly.

Here follows the code that I am currently using:

```
dataset <- reactive({

   filename <- paste(input$estado, 
      paste(paste("input_plot_list",
            input$periodo, sep = "_"), "RData", sep = "."), 
      sep = "_")

   load(filename)

})
```

I hope I was clear, any help is much appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? Was the filename correctly constructed?

Comment: warmoverflow, the filename is correct, i've already tested it. The problem is that the file just doesn't load..

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Or did the `dataset()` reactive function run? Also try full path for the file and see if it works.

Comment: `dados <- eventReactive(input$go, {get(load(paste(input$estado, paste(paste("input_plot_list", input$periodo, sep = "_"), "RData", sep = "."), sep = "_")))} )
  
  
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(dados()[[2]])
  
    
    
    })`

Comment: That was the solution... Cheer mans